# Insert a parameter into Where Clause

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have this query which i want to get rank from the data on my database

```
set @urut:=0;
set @rankhrg:=0;
select @urut:=@urut+1 as urut, a.id_tender, b.nama_tender, b.nomor_tender, b.tgl_close1 as tgl_close,
(SELECT rankhrg 
from (select sum(tot_harga) as hrg_twr, id_rekanan, id_tender, @rankhrg:=@rankhrg+1 as rankhrg from tb_real_barang where id_tender = s.id_tender  group by id_rekanan) as rank_harga
left join tb_master_tender s on s.id_tender = b.id_tender
where rank_harga.id_rekanan = a.id_rekanan
order by rank_harga.hrg_twr asc) as ranking
                                        from tb_real_tender a
                                        left join tb_master_tender b on a.id_tender = b.id_tender
                                        where a.id_rekanan = 1
                                        order by convert(a.id_tender,unsigned) desc
```

i want to pass id_tender into the select inside the select when i want to get rankhrg :

```
select sum(tot_harga) as hrg_twr, id_rekanan, id_tender, 
       @rankhrg:=@rankhrg+1 as rankhrg 
from tb_real_barang 
where id_tender = s.id_tender  
group by id_rekanan
```

but I always get error that said that s.id_tender is unknown in where clause.

can someone guide me how to pass the parameter into that insert?
thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not joining with that table `tb_master_tender` and neither it's present in outer query `FROM` clause. So, you need to do a `JOIN` separately for that inner query like below

```
select sum(trb.tot_harga) as hrg_twr, 
trb.id_rekanan, 
trb.id_tender, 
@rankhrg:=@rankhrg+1 as rankhrg 
from tb_real_barang trb
left join tb_master_tender s on trb.id_tender = s.id_tender  
group by trb.id_rekanan
```

Comment: what i want to do is geting s.id_tender value as parameter for trb.id_tender and s.id_tender, and it already present in outer query from `from` clause..are it is not possible to it?

Comment: NO, that's what I said, in outer query you are joining with that table. So, can't refer it like that way. You will have to join that table separately in inner query.